# How to move database-related code to a separate service?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I'm new to Angular and Ionic. I've started a simple app that adds items to a Firebase Db. So far so good.

I have two methods in my component ts file:

```
add(item: string) {
  this.items.push({
    item: item
  })
  .catch(error => console.log('ERROR ' + error));
}

remove(key: string) {
  this.af.object( `/items/${key}`).remove()
    .catch(error => console.log('ERROR ' + error));
}
```

I would like to move the above methods to a separate service class, so I created a new file:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class ItemService {
   constructor() {
   }
}
```

But the above methods reference `items` which is a FirebaseListObservable and `af` which is an AngularFireDatabase injected in the controller.

How is it possible to modify the above 2 methods so that they can moved in the service?

Answer (score 0):

White a injectable service as you started and define these methods. Then firebase db will return a observable and in your service you can process these data and then again return observable which can be subscribed to consume and process view

```
@Injectable()
export class ItemService {
   constructor(private firebaseService: FirebaseService) {
   }

add(item: string) {

  // if firebase service returns observable, then map will precess and return observable whcih can be subscribed
  this.fireBaseService.get().map( (data) => {
     return this.items.push({
       item: data.item
    })
     .catch(error => console.log('ERROR ' + error));
  })
}


// same f0r remove
remove(key: string) {
   return this.af.object( `/items/${key}`).remove()
    .catch(error => console.log('ERROR ' + error));
}
}
// if I understood the question correctly
```